# “interpreter readable” printing (in R)

Tags: r, printing

I am wondering whether there is a way to print objects in an “interpreter readable” way, which would do something looking like this:

```
> x <- c(1:5,8)
> print.ir(x)
 c(1,2,3,4,5,8)
> x <- matrix(1:4, ncol=2)
> print.ir(x)
 matrix(c(1,2,3,4), ncol=2, nrow=2)
```

So that the result could be copy-pasted in a R script or in another R session.

Comment: ...and its what we like to use on SO for small data examples so we can paste them into R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `dput()` for this:

```
x <- c(1:5,8)
dput(x)
c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8)

x <- matrix(1:4, ncol=2)
dput(x)
structure(1:4, .Dim = c(2L, 2L))
```

Try it:

```
z <- structure(1:4, .Dim = c(2L, 2L))
z
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Why it isn’t in the 'see also' section of the man pages of `str` or `print` is a mystery...

Comment: @Elvis It is, in fact, in the Description of `?str`, but I agree there is lots of scope for improvement in the docs.

Comment: Oh yes. As I know what `str` is for, I didn’t look for this information in Description :) 

Most R documentation is good and most of the time I am happy with it, in particular I appreciate that it quotes bibliography for methods and algorithms.